# Python Pandas groupby

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df as

```
Name      Date      Sale
John   2018-3-23   10000
John   2018-3-24   12000
John   2018-3-28   11000
Mary   2018-3-25   15000
Mary   2018-3-29   12000
Mary   2018-3-31   13000
Sam    2018-3-25   18000
Sam    2018-3-26   12000
Sam    2018-3-27   14000
```

I would like to find the Sale of each person on their last date.

```
Name      Date      Sale
John   2018-3-28   11000
Mary   2018-3-31   13000
Sam    2018-3-27   14000
```

I tried to write the `groupby` statement as

```
df.groupby('Name')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.max())
```

But it only displays `Name` and `Date` but not `Sale`.

What is the correct command?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = df.groupby('Name')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.max()).reset_index()
b = a.merge(df, on = list(a), how = 'left')
```